# Quick sort in java not sorting correctly

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have this QuickSort algorithm that seems to sort a given input array but not completely :

```
public static int partition(int[] A,int low,int high){
    int pivot=A[high-1];
    int i=low-1;
    int temp=0;
    for(int j=low;j<A.length-1;j++){
        if(A[j]<pivot){
            i++;
            temp = A[j];
            A[j]=A[i];
            A[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    temp=A[high-1];
    A[high-1]=A[i+1];
    A[i+1]=temp;
    return i+1;
}

public static void Qsort(int[] A,int low,int high){
    if(low<high){
        int p=partition(A,low,high);
        Qsort(A,low,p-1);
        Qsort(A,p+1,high);
      }
}
```

i'm calling the method Qsort in main as such

```
Qsort(arr,0,arr.length);
```

for example this array is sorted correctly

```
6,5,3,7,1,2
```

but this one

```
{6,5,3,7,1,2,4} is sorted like this {1 3 2 4 5 6 7}
```

if i change the last index to 8 instead of 4 it works. It's confusing.
i think the error is minor but i can't find it.

thanks for the help.

**EDITED:**
The correct solution to the problem:

```
public static int partition(int[] A,int low,int high){
   int pivot=A[high];
   int i=low;
   int temp=0;
   for(int j=low;j<high;j++){
      if(A[j]<pivot){
         temp = A[j];
         A[j]=A[i];
         A[i]=temp;
         i++;
      }
  }
  temp=A[high];
  A[high]=A[i];
  A[i]=temp;
  return i;
}
```

and the call to Qsort in main should be:(it was Important)

```
Qsort(arr,0,arr.length-1);
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code - it'll make it much easier to read. It would also help greatly if you used more meaningful variable names.

Comment: And shouldn't your partition method stop at `h` rather than at `A.length - 1`?

Comment: I suggest you step through your code using your debugger to understand what it is doing. Are you sure `j<A.length-1` is right?

Comment: I won't even bother looking at your code, problems like this 99% of the time are due to overlooking a incorrect > or >=. Compare your code to psuedocode and you should find the problem in no time.

Comment: It is your algorithm that is not working correctly, I suggest that you improve it. Lookup quick sort on Google. Your partition() method can and should be improved, that is where your error is. Think about the difference between the array that gets sorted correctly and the one that does not (size).

Comment: Even if i changed it to h it will still give the same output.@Peter Lawrey

Comment: What the algorithm is doing: choosing the last index as a pivot and then compare the remaining elements to it. placing all elements <pivot between 0 and i and all elements >pivot between i+2 and j.
and then swapping i+1 with the pivot.
@GermannArlington

Comment: I can read the code and I can see what it is doing. Did YOU think about the difference how YOUR algorithm works with even and odd sizes of the array? I was pointing you in the direction of your problem, I don't intend to rewrite the code for you...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int partition(int[] A,int low,int high){
    int pivotIndex=0;
    int pivot=A[pivotIndex];
    int i=low;    
    int temp=A[pivotIndex];
    A[pivotIndex]=A[high];
    A[high]=temp;
    for(int j=low;j<high;j++){
        if(A[j]<pivot){
            temp = A[j];
            A[j]=A[i];
            A[i]=temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    temp=A[high-1];
    A[high-1]=A[i+1];
    A[i+1]=temp;
    return i;
}
```

There are a few improvements necessary to make it work:

1. Choose the pivot index not as high -1, for the sake of simplicity let's take 0
2. swap the element pivotIndex with high before entering the for loop
3. Increase your storeIndex i after swapping, instead of  before
4. Return the storeIndex i instead of i++

Comment: Thanks for your help i used some of your steps to improve my code.I updated the solution above.